# Weird error in Command Prompt, trying to install package with PIP

Tags: git, installation, pip, command, prompt

So I am trying to install a python package with pip in my command prompt, but I keep getting this error:

ERROR: Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q https://github.com/BurntSushi/nflgame.git 'C:\Users\samfe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-nbf_m66n'
ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?

I am following the directions from a git hub post to install it, and it says to use

```
pip install git+https://github.com/BurntSushi/nflgame.git
```

to download it. Not sure why the prompt says that I need to install 'git', because that isn't a python package...Let me know if you know how to fix this.

Thanks!!

Comment: You’re using git to install a package. Is it installed? If not you should install it.

Comment: Since you're using `git+https://`, pip requires the `git` in order to fetch the data.  It sounds like you either don't have Git installed, or it's not on your PATH where pip can find it.  You need to fix that.  Alternatively, you can install the latest release of it from PyPI (thought it appears to be pretty old).  It looks like `pip install nflgame-redux` is a better choice (see https://github.com/derek-adair/nflgame).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ERROR%3A+Cannot+find+command+git

Comment: yea I do I have it installed

Comment: @SamuelDiSorbo Check it's available in `%PATH%`. Just run `git` from the command line.